# Rails 4 match all routes for one controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a controller with a number of static pages and I would ideally like to route them all with a wildcard.

Is it possible to do something *like* the following?

```
get 'static/:action'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use the `show` action:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :static, param: :page, only: :show #-> url.com/static/:page

#app/controllers/static_controller.rb
class StaticController < ApplicationController
   def show
      render "#{params[:page]}"
   end
end
```

This way, you can pass the "page" directly through the link and have it all handled by Rails:

```
 <%= link_to "About", static_path("page") %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need something like `get 'static/:action', to: 'static#show'` and then in your `StaticController` show action render the correct static page based on the `params[:action]` parameter.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults for more.

Comment: Doesn't the old technique work anymore, e.g., `:controller/:action` type thing? I haven't tried that for a long time.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, I suppose, although in this case it doesn't seem that bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can route something like

```
get '*path', to: 'static#show'
```